# computer startup script reporting success to a server

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, scripting, batch

I am using Group Policy to deploy a computer startup script that tries to uninstall one program and install another. I need this script to report its status (whether a certain file exists on the system, which would mean that the installation succeeded).

My first idea was to mount a network share and drop a text file in there. Is there a better way to do this? Right now, I am using a batch file, although I would be open to learning a bit of PowerShell if it was the best option.

Comment: did you mean "uninstall one program and INSTALL another"

Comment: Oh dear. Fixed.

Comment: Also do these applications use window compliant installers? As in uses the msi installer?

Comment: Yes, they use MSI installers, though that should be irrelevant. I need to check for the presence of two files, actually, one for some cleanup the script does, and one for the installation.

Comment: well if the msi components are working correctly then you wouldn't have to worry about file remenants, also msi's can have logging enabled...

Comment: As the question title says, I need the script to report its success back to me, not to a log file on the computer. Also, as I said in the last comment, one of the file checks is not related to the MSI, but is "for some cleanup the script does".

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would probably use the text file.  On success:

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME% >> z:\path\success.txt
```

On failure:

```
echo %COMPUTERNAME% >> z:\path\failure.txt
```

Someone else might have something that works better, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use the network share method personally then I have our monitoring application check that folder periodically for files matching "error*.log" and fire off an alert if there is one.. that's for our servers. For our workstations our tech support staff checks it around lunch time and makes a list of systems they need to visit, doesn't happen often.